# How to configure xdg-open to open links in VMware Horizon Client

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, xdg

I had to reinstall Ubuntu for the first time today after it stopped booting. The last thing on my list I need to fix is setting up VMware Horizon Client. I have installed version 4.8.

I need to log onto remote workstations via a web portal, and historically clicking on the workstation would launch horizon client. However now when I get the message '.... wants to open this application' and I select 'Open xdg-open', instead of launching horizon, it just does nothing.

Is anyone able to assist at all?